# DocuSign API Email Verification

Tags: docusignapi

I'm having an issue receiving the verification email from DocuSign that is needed to create an account under my master account to connect for use with API.  The emails don't appear to be hitting my firewall, nor are they showing up in my email.  Does anyone know if these emails are coming from docusign.com, docusign.net, or some other domain?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please finish the tour and you will understand [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and modify question accordingly to minimal working example. Without posting your code you risk removal of your question. With your stated trail and error code... people are more willing to help you so we both can learn. Enjoy SO ;-)

Answer (score 1):

In Demo emails will come from `dse_demo@docusign.net` and in PROD it should come from `dse@docusign.net`. Also please check your Spam/Junk folder if it landing on these folder as per your email server policy.